# NoSQL database for relational data structure

Tags: sql, node.js, database, database-design, nosql

I'm creating a photo gallery SPA with angularJS (front & back) and nodejs (server). I'm asking myself which type of database I should use to store the gallery/photo knowing :

- I'll have two main classes : `Photo` and `Gallery`
- A `Gallery` will contain either another `Gallery` or a `Photo` (infinite stacking of gallery possible in theory ...)
- Easy data manipulation, for example, I need the ability to move a `photo`/`gallery` to another `Gallery` easily, or a full branch (move a tree of 4 nested gallery to another one)

related SQL structure:

```
Photo (photo_id, title, filename, gallery_id) //gallery_id is a foreign key to Gallery table
Gallery (gallery_id, title, parent_id) //parent_id is NULL when no parent (root gallery)
```

This data structure is quite simple but relational, so using a SQL database like postgresql with NodeJS would be OK.

How would you structure that with a  noSQL databases  like mongoDB ? (maybe with my relational structure data it's  totally out of the question ?)

Is it a case where traditional relational SQL databases is preferable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use mongoDB for keeping nested structures as it will enable indexing to n level and enable querying on those indexes as well.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Do you have any concrete example ? I'll take a look at the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to insert a record into a collection called photogallery.
You need not have to pre-create collection.

```
db.photogallery.insert(
{
 photo_id: "1",
 phototitle: "phototitle",
 filename: "filename",
 gallery: {
    gallerytitle: "gallerytitle",
    parentgallery: "parentgallery"
 }
}
)
```